# Can somebody check my proof that two categories are isomorphic?

Tags: solution-verification, category-theory

### The main problem

So after watching a particular Youtube video by a certain Mr. Oliver introducing basic category theory, I decided (as one does) to write a proof that two categories are isomorphic. Might somebody check for any mistakes that I might have made, or give any advice on notation, proofwriting or studying?

### The proof

#### 1. Definitions

Define the category $\mathcal{C}_{Notes}$ to be a category such that:

- $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C}_{Notes})=\{\ldots, G_3, G\sharp_3, A_4, A\sharp_4, B_4, \ldots\}$
- $\mathrm{hom}(\mathcal{C}_{Notes})=\{T_n | n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ ($T_n$ being the function which transposes a note $n$ semitones up)
- $T_mT_n=T_{m+n}$

We shall now prove that composition satisfies the identity law and the associative law.
$\mathbf{Proof:}$
Consider the morphism $T_0$.
By definition of note transposition (which shan't be defined for brevity), $T_0(X)=X\mspace{3mu}(X\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C}_{Notes}))$.
Thus we have proven that there exists an identity morphism.
Now we prove
$\forall T_m,T_n\in\mathrm{hom}(\mathcal{C}_{Notes})\forall X\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C}_{Notes}):
T_mT_n(X)=T_nT_m(X)$.
$T_mT_n(X):=T_{m+n}(X)=T_{n+m}(X):=T_nT_m(X)$
$\square$

Define the category $\mathcal{C}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ to be a category such that:

- $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C}_{\mathbb{Z}})=\mathbb{Z}$
- $\mathrm{hom}(\mathcal{C}_{\mathbb{Z}})=\{+_n | n\in\mathbb{Z}\}\mspace{4mu} (+_n(p):=p+n)$
- $+_m+_n=+_{m+n}$

By a similar logic, we can prove that composition satisfies the identity law and the associative law.

### 2. Main Proof

Consider the mapping $F:\mathcal{C}_{Notes}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ which maps as such:

- $A_4\rightarrow0$
- $T_n\rightarrow+_n$
- $T_n(X)\rightarrow+_n(F(X))$

We now prove that $F$ is a functor.
$\mathbf{Proof:}$
By definition, $F$ maps $T_0$ to $+_0$, thus preserving identity.
$F(T_mT_n)=F(T_{m+n})=+_{m+n}=+_m+_n=F(T_m)F(T_n)$
Thus we have satisfied the conditions for $F$ to be a functor.
$\square$

Now, consider the mapping $G:\mathcal{C}_{\mathbb{Z}}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}_{Notes}$ which maps as such:

- $0\rightarrow A_4$
- $+_n\rightarrow T_n$
- $+_n(X)\rightarrow T_n(F(X))$

By a similar logic, $G$ is a functor.

Finally, we are to prove that $F$ and $G$ are cofunctors of eachother.
$\mathbf{Proof:}$
$G(F(A_4))=G(0)=A_4$
$F(G(0))=F(A_4)=0$
$G(F(T_n))=G(+_n)=T_n$
$F(G(+_n))=F(T_n)=+_n$
Thus we have proven that F and G are cofunctors.
$\blacksquare$

### Closing words

Good lord, that took me ***way*** too long to write.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you understand correctly what a category is. In each case, you define a category $\mathcal{C}$ by a set of objects $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ (so far so good), and a set $\mathrm{hom}(\mathcal{C})$ of functions $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})\to \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ (or at least that is what I understand from your definition). For instance in your second example you have functions $+_n: \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$.

But that is not the definition of a category. Rather, you should have a set $\mathrm{hom}(A,B)$ for each objects $A,B\in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$. So in your second example you should have a set $\mathrm{hom}(m,n)$ for each integers $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}$.

It seems to me that what you actually want to do is to define a category where there is exactly one morphism between each two objects: $\mathrm{hom}(A,B)$ is a singleton with just the "transposing" morphism as its unique element. At least that is my interpretation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh, I really should read more into this. I'm gonna go research a bit and rewrite this proof... where could I put the revision?